# MongoDb Aggregation Framework - Can $sum result be used in $push?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

Is it possible to add the results of a $sum to an array in grouping?

Something like:

```
{
 "$group" :
  {
   _id : {ProductId: "$ProductId", Day: "$Day"},
   Products : {$push:{clicks: {$sum: "$clicks"}}}
  }
}
```

I would like to store the calculated value of $sum into an array. Can this be done in a grouping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it with second group operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$group : {_id : {ProductId : "$ProductId", Day : "$Day"}, 
               clicks : {$sum : "$clicks"}}},
    {$group : {_id : "$_id", Products : {$push : {clicks : "$clicks"}}}}
)
```

Comment: Oi! Of coarse! :) Thanks Meng!